# Easting and Northing range in UTM

Tags: utm, ux

I'm working in the development of an user interface in which the user should be able to enter a UTM coordinate in the following format:

I don't know much about these type of systems, but I do want to provide a good user interface with client side validation. I know that the zone will be 1-60 with a plus or minus sign to determine the hemisphere. I would like to know what would be the valid range to input for easting and northing field. Currently I'm just checking if 'Double' number is provided, but I know the valid range should be more narrow.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the northings about 10,000,000m max
For the eastings, 0ish to 1,000,000ish meters since the central meridian of every zone is 500,000 m and you will never get to 0 or 1,000,000   Remember the equator has a false northing of 0m in the northern hemisphere, increasing poleward and 10,000,000m in the southern hemisphere decreasing to the South Pole

Comment: FYI, the Danes want to map Greenland (and its offshore) with a 'wide' UTM zone, but the transverse Mercator algorithm has to support the East-West extension.